# How to let a container shrink when all other containers are as small as possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is that the "content" always gets a scrollbar when "shrink" is needed as its size gets reduced as well. But it has to be "shrinkable" as its content can be larger than the available space.

How can I achieve this? Or is it just not possible?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 100;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
}

#content {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    take as much space as content allows to take. shrink if there is not enough space.
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    take all the available space between header and footer, shrink in case there is not enough space but only when header is as small as possible. do not shrink as the header still can be shrunken to prevent scrollbars as long they are not needed...
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    take as much space as your content needs
  </div>
 </div>
```

Another try to explain it:

The footer should take as much space as its content needs. Than it should not grow and not shrink. The header should take as much space as the content does not need. If there is not enough space, the header should shrink until a fixed min-height. The content should take as much space possible between the header and the footer. If there is not enough space, it should shrink as well, but only when the header has reached its min-height.

And another try with some numbers:

1. UC1: The whole container has 100px available. The footer takes 20px,
   the content requires an other 50px and the header takes 20px as
   well. 
   In this the container should grow by 10px so the whole 100px are covered.
2. UC2: The whole container has 100px available. The footer takes 20px, the content requires 40px and the header 60px. In this case the whole container would need 120px. As the header can shrink for 20px (to its min size) the content should stay at 40px.
3. UC3: The whole container has 100px available. The footer takes 20px, the content requires 70px and the header 50px. So the container would need 140px.
   In this case the header should shrink to 40px and the container to 40px as well to stay at 100px for the whole container.

Comment: You want the header and footer to take as much space as they need then the content take all leftover space ?

Comment: I reallly don't know what you want to achieve....

Comment: @ZohirSalak I have updated the post with an other try to explain it...

Comment: @xmaster Update with an other try to explain it

Comment: try explaining this line `The header should take as much space as the content does not need`

Comment: a. Are you trying to set the height of #content as the difference between #header and #footer height? b. is there any max-height or just min?

Comment: @ZohirSalak added numeric examples

Comment: @A.Meshu a. height of #content should be "container - header - footer" b. there are no max-heights. In case all elements in the #container are reaching their min-height, the #container should scroll.

Comment: Way too specific for css alone, you'll have to include js i'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lot of properties, you can simplify your code like below:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /*full height*/
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px; /*fixed height*/
  flex-shrink:10; /* Shrink more that the other*/
}

#content {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1; /*Fill remaining space*/
  overflow: auto; /*allow the scroll to appear if not enough space*/
  min-height: 100px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    take as much space as content allows to take. shrink if there is not enough space.
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    take all the available space between header and footer, shrink in case there is not enough space but only when header is as small as possible. do not shrink as the header still can be shrinked to prevent scrollbars as long they are not needed...
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    take as much space as your content needs
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes... I can remove all the "default" values... but how does this solve the problem!?!
Or is there something I have not seen?

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer you were overcomplicating this by adding a lot of non needed properties that aren't the default one. All you need is (1) flex-grow:1 to content (2) a big flex-shrink + height to header (3) height:100% to body and html to make sure you have a full height